# Query Postgres - Same table compare dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have 2 queries the same table and that has the following columns
Code - Date - Item - Record

My first query:

```
SELECT * FROM "TABLE" pt   
WHERE pt.Item IN (1,2,3)  
AND CAST(pt.Date AS DATE) between '2015/12/01' AND '2015/12/10'  
AND pt.Code  in (x,y)  
AND pt.Record > 60
```

The second query is equals first, but only 'Code' values are different.

```
 SELECT * FROM "TABLE" pt   
 WHERE pt.Item IN (1,2,3)  
 AND CAST(pt.Date AS DATE) between '2015/12/01' AND '2015/12/10'  
 AND pt.Code  in (a,b)  
 AND pt.Record > 60
```

I need get result in one query
Something like this:

```
Item - DateFirstQuery - FirstDateGreaterThanFirstQueryDate  
1 - 2015-12-01 00:00:01 - 2015-12-01 00:00:02 (Next date from the first query in  the second query)
```

Beginning and end dates

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Maybe You need `UNION ALL`?

Comment: FirstDateGreaterThanFirstQueryDate, nothing else, like same item, or code or?